# Angular and Asp.net Web Api 2 token

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angular, asp.net-web-api2

I am working with authentication using Angular and .Net Web API 2 back end. My registration route, and other resources are working, however the login/token is not.

In postman, this request works and I get the token back:
 [image]

In angular my code looks like the following:

```
  credentials.grant_type = "password";
  credentials.userName = "email@email.com";
  credentials.password = "asdfasdf";
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlenconded' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:58352/Token', credentials, options).map((response: Response) => {
    return response.json();
  });
```

However, I get the response:

```
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}
```

In Angular.js (or Angular 1) I used transformRequest to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick!

```
  let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
  urlSearchParams.append('userName', 'email@email.com');
  urlSearchParams.append('password', 'asdfasdf');
  urlSearchParams.append('grant_type', 'password');
  let body = urlSearchParams.toString()
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlenconded' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:58352/Token', body, options).map((response: Response) => {
    return response.json();
  });
```